# SQL update statement can insert NULL value to foreign key column

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery

I have below two tables:

```
EMPLOYEE (employee_ID  primary key)(Foreign key Department_id reference department(department_id))
```

```
employee_id First_name  Last_name  Department_id  Salary  Commission

154         Aaan        Eaan         80            6000    0.2

166         Baan        Faan         80            7000    0.1

167         Caan        Gaan         80            7000    0.3

169         Daan        Haan         80            8000    0.4
```

DEPARTMENTS(Department_id  primary key)

```
Department_id  Dept_name  location

10             AA         1700

40             BB         1800

70             CC         1900

80             DD         2000
```

I have below update code

```
UPDATE employee a
SET department_id=(select department_id 
                   from departments
                   where location = 2100),
    (salary,comission)=(select 1.1*AVG(salary), 1.5*AVG(comission)
                        from employee b
                        where a.department_id = b.department_id)
where first_name||' '||last_name = 'Caan Gaan';
```

My questions is will above code execute? There is no location 2100 in departments table, will null value inserted?Please help

Comment: Why not try it and see.... ?

Comment: I tried, the null value inserted

Answer (score 1):

The above code will be executed.Yes, null value is inserted in this case. Please read the oracle docs here - http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/data_int.htm#sthref3085

It will give you the main concept why null value will insert in Foreign Key column.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes `NULL` will be inserted.

You are setting the `department_id` using a *scalar subquery*.  Such a subquery returns exactly one column and at most one row.  If there is no row in the result set, then the value is `NULL`.

If a location could have more than one departments, then your query is dangerous.  If it returns multiple values, then you will get an error.  One solution is to add `where rownum = 1`.  Another is to use an aggregation function to ensure that only one value is returned.

Comment: Thank you Gordon, the null value is inserted, and I don't understand why it's not violating the foreign key constraint since there is no null value in the department(department_id) .<br> the subquery will always return 1 column and 1 row

Comment: is it has to do with index?

Comment: @Al.D . . . `NULL` values are allowed for foreign key references, unless the column is declared `NOT NULL`.  They simply mean that there is no matching value.

Answer (score 0):

It'll either be returning:

1) `null`

OR

2) Error if the department_id is set to NOT NULL or it is a Primary key

Answer (score 0):

Consider this your column should accept NULL values.

If you set column NOT NULL you can go change it in Table design view easily to nullable :
Right click on table, Design, check allow nulls.